# difference between composer install and composer install -o

Tags: php, composer-php

Can you help me to find the difference between composer install and composer install -o.

Normally composer install -o generate an optimized autoloder file, but when i generates it it was like the other file with composer install.

my classmapfile have many path but the result of composer install -o and composer install steel the same can you explain this for me ?
can you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track: The `-o` option creates an "optimized" autoloader that essentially is a classmap for every class that otherwise would be loaded through PSR-0 or PSR-4. Composer will scan all directories that are mentioned for PSR-0 and PSR-4 just like it would always to with `classmap` entries.

This might already answer your question: If your project only has a `classmap` entry and nothing else, there is no difference in the result.

Note that it is not the best idea to prematurely optimize the autoloading by forcing the `classmap` if you could also use one of the PSR schemes. Using only the classmap will hinder development because every time a new class is created, you'd have to dump the autoloader with that new entry. Also note that creating *huge* classmaps might actually be slower than PSR-based class loading, because you trade code execution time for allocated memory, and at some point allocating memory for *all* classes in every request even if they are not being used will be slower than executing PSR autoloading. You'd have to measure your individual application performance with both a normal and an optimized autoloader to decide which one is actually better.

More info [in the docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md)

Comment: my classmapfile have many path but the result of composer install -o and composer install steel the same can you explain this for me

Comment: It's possible that there are no differences if all parts are only using classmap autoloading. What is your `composer.json` (please edit your question to add it there instead of cramming it into a comment without formatting).